# Correct Syntax for clearing SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently learning how to use Pandas, and I'm in a situation where I'm attempting to replace missing data (Horsepower feature) using a best-fit line generated from linear regression with the Displacement column. What I'm doing is iterating through only the parts of the dataframe that are marked as NaN in the Horsepower column and replacing the data by feeding in the value of Displacement in that same row into the best-fit algorithm. My code looks like this:

```
for row, value in auto_data.HORSEPOWER[pd.isnull(auto_data.HORSEPOWER)].iteritems():
    auto_data.HORSEPOWER[row] = int(round(slope * auto_data.DISPLACEMENT[row] + intercept))
```

Now, the code works and the data is replaced as expected, but it generates the `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I run it. I understand why the warning is generated, and that in this case I'm fine, but if there is a better way to iterate through the subset, or a method that's just more elegant, I'd rather avoid chained indexing that could cause a real problem in the future.

I've looked through the docs, and through other answers on Stack Overflow. All solutions to this seem to use `.loc`, but I just can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to get the subset of NaN rows using `.loc` Any help is appreciated. If it helps, the dataframe looks like this:

```
auto_data.dtypes
Out[15]: 
MPG             float64
CYLINDERS         int64
DISPLACEMENT    float64
HORSEPOWER      float64
WEIGHT            int64
ACCELERATION    float64
MODELYEAR         int64
NAME             object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the DataFrame row-by-row, it would be more efficient to calculate the extrapolated values in a vectorized way for the entire column:

```
y = (slope * auto_data['DISPLACEMENT'] + intercept).round()
```

and then use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) to replace the NaN values:

```
auto_data['HORSEPOWER'].update(y)
```

Using `update` works for the particular case of replacing NaN values.
[Ed Chum's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360554/190597) shows how to replace the value in arbitrary rows by using a boolean mask and `auto_data.loc`.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
auto_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'HORSEPOWER':[1, np.nan, 2],
    'DISPLACEMENT': [3, 4, 5]})
slope, intercept = 2, 0.5
y = (slope * auto_data['DISPLACEMENT'] + intercept).round()
auto_data['HORSEPOWER'].update(y)
print(auto_data)
```

yields

```
   DISPLACEMENT  HORSEPOWER
0             3           6
1             4           8
2             5          10
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you should be able to just do:

```
auto_data.loc[auto_data[HORSEPOWER].isnull(),'HORSEPOWER'] = np.round(slope * auto_data['DISPLACEMENT'] + intercept)
```

The above will be vectorised and avoid looping, the error you get is from doing this:

```
auto_data.HORSEPOWER[row]
```

I think if you did:

```
auto_data.loc[row,'HORSEPOWER']
```

then the warning should not be raised